# Android-Writing in Firebase Database an Arraylist inside of a node

Tags: android, database, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write an `ArrayList` `ArticleDesire`  of `Article.Class` inside a User of my database, my `Article` class has a String `titre` and an `ArrayList` `motcle`, in the database the `motcle` array won't show up in
my Database i Checked and it wasn't empty [image: Dataset]

Here is my `Add` `ArticleDesire` Method

```
 public void addArticleDesire(final ArrayList<Article> motcle, String Userid)
    {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        DatabaseReference user = mDatabase.child(Userid);
        final DatabaseReference keylist = user.child("ArticleDesire");
        keylist.setValue(motcle);
   }
```

My Article constructor

```
 public Article(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String titre) {
        if (arrayList.isEmpty()){
            Log.w("Arraylist","VIDE");
        }
        this.motcle=new ArrayList(arrayList);
        if (motcle.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            Log.w("Arraylist"," NON VIDE"+motcle);
        }
        this.titre=titre;
    }
```

I call the `AddArticleDesire` in an `activity`, I Checked the constructor when called and the `ArrayList` isn't empty and the articles are in it.
is it possible when having different constructors in the `Article` Class, it can interfere with the Writing?

Comment: can you show the complete code of your `Article` class and the part of your Activity, where you set up the ArrayLists and call `addArticleDesire()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firebase Realtime Database` doesn't store arrays. It stores sets of information(dictionaries/associate arrays). So the closest solution you can get is:

```
countries: {
  0: "Spain",
  1: "France",
  2: "Italy",
  3: "Poland",
  4: "Belgium"
}
```

So this should be the solution that you are looking for.
If you wanna read more information and best practices regarding arrays in Realtime Database I suggest you to give a look to the next article:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Finally, if you recently started to work on your app and your database, I suggest you to switch it to `Firestore`, which allows you to store arrays: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays?hl=es-419

Comment: Hi Fransisco. Your sign-off has some very kind wishes, but we prefer answers to focus on the technical material here. I often post the following advice for new users: _We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._